# List template displays wrong users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I downloaded lists from one site collection and uploaded them to another. The problem is that in the column for "Person or Group" the users are now different. Is this because on the new site collection the users do not exist? I figured a default would be created for them or at least the name would be written down.

If this is the issue, then I was wondering if there is a workaround because on the new site collection I'm unable to add new users at the moment... since it just says I gave them an external invitation, but the users do not show up in the People and Groups.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens, I'm fairly certain, that when the data is exported as a template, it persists user fields as list item IDs that are associated with the user information list.

Since this list varies from site collection to site collection, if you are importing it into a new site collection, there is no guarantee that the IDs are the same person or exist at all.

You should be able to verify this by creating the list in the same site collection it originated from and see that the users are the same as the source, because their IDs match.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I just checked and you were right. Do you know of any good methods to transfer the list while still preserving the person?

Comment: To persist it as a person/group column, you would need to do it in a programmatic way, so you could read the user, see if they exist, and update them properly. If that isn't possible, an alternative approach would be to create a single line of text field to store the data instead.